# How to connect to an Access database using the OleDb namespace in .NET?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, ado.net, oledb

I want to use an Access database for my Windows Forms application. (written with C#)
I have used OleDb namespace for connecting, and I'm able to select the records from the source using the `OleDbConnection` and `ExecuteReader` objects.
However, I can't insert, update or delete records yet.

My code is the following:

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strCon);

 try
 {
     string con="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=xyz.mdb;Persist Security Info=True";

     con.Open();

     OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO DPMaster(DPID, DPName, ClientID, ClientName) VALUES('53', 'we', '41', 'aw')", con);

     int a = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

     //OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM DPMaster", con);
     //OleDbDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();

     //while (dr.Read())
     //{
     //    MessageBox.Show(dr[2].ToString());
     //}

     MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
 }
 catch
 {
     MessageBox.Show("cannot");
 }
```

If I the commentted block is executed, the application works fine. But the insert block doesn't.

Knowing this, why I am unable to insert, update or delete database records?

Comment: Instead of catching the exception, you should see what the exception says.  It should give you an indication of what's going wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*?

Comment: Do catch(Exception ex) and show ex.Message, or see ex detail

Comment: You shouldn't use access, your application will become slow and the data integrity unstable, and you'll have to migrate the entire db if you go to MS-SQL. Use FireBird embedded if you need an embeddable database. It has the added benefit that you can plug in the embeddable db file into the full firebird server once this becomes necessary, and it's cross-platform.

Comment: @Quandary: @Abilash is not using Access -- he's using Jet, which happens to be installed on all copies of Windows from Win2000 on. That's a great advantage of using it, that it's available for your application without need of installation. It's also perfectly suitable database engine for a whole host of applications. Adding in the dependency on SQL Server or Firebird brings installation/configuration/administrations issues while for any particular application it may not bring with it any useful benefits.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: No, he's using JET to access Access. Adding SQL Server or Firebird doesn't bring any issues you won't have with Access. Besides, you cannot avoid administering a database once you have one, no matter what database on which server. That said, one shouldn't use raw SQL anyway. One should use an ORM tool, like nHibernate.

Comment: No, @Quandary, it's using Jet to access a Jet data file. Access is a completely separate product that happens to use the Jet/ACE database engine as its default database. Jet is installed on ALL versions of Windows from 2000 on, so, you're just WRONG in regard to whether something extra needs to be installed. With Jet, it doesn't (assuming you're deploying on Windows). With the other databases, your app has to include the database engine.

Comment: @Quandary: the ORM (nHibernate) comment strikes me as ludicrous. Care to point at some kind of justification for such a sweeping assertion?

Comment: David-W-Fenton: SQL injection, vendor lock-in, bad database design, database-independence, platform-independence, JET-version-independence, lower maintenance effort, faster development. And he's using Jet to access an Access database. Jet basically is the Access data backend, Access is only the GUI. Do you think Access works without Jet ? Maybe you should try...

Comment: On SQL injection, Jet/ACE is vulnerable to very few of the usual exploits, and really, for most of them, only when it's used inappropriately (e.g., as a back end to a web application).

Comment: "Vendor lock-in" suggests that you're really just calling for programming to a database abstraction layer. What is appropriate in that context is going to depend on your operating environment. My guess is that you have a web-based orientation, which is not going to be very applicable to Access/Jet/ACE.

Comment: "Bad database design" is user error, not a function of the database engine. You can design a bad or wrong schema in the most robust industrial-strength enterprise database like Oracle, as well as in Jet/ACE/Access. This is not something inherent to the database engine -- it's a PEBCAK issue.

Comment: "Jet basically is the Access data backend" -- this assertions suggests you don't have any deep understanding of Access as front-end development tool, since Access can use almost any back-end data source, and offers multiple different ways to use them.

Comment: "Do you think Access works without Jet ?" See ADP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem that I encountered myself is as:

You've added the mdb file to your solution and every time you run the program it will be copied into debug folder.

So you can select from it but deleting rows doesn't affect the original file you have in your solution.

Check for it.

Comment: +1 - As it is a database, I would never have thought about adding it to my solution, so never would have come up with that as a probable problem.

Comment: As you said I have removed the database from the project and used from other location.Now its working fine. The records are inserted into the database.  Thanks a lot Jane..

Answer (score 2):

First, never strangle your exception. It is better to let your exception bubble up so that you may get important information regarding what is not working properly. It is better to write:

```
con.Open();
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO DPMaster(DPID,DPName,ClientID,ClientName) VALUES('53','we','41','aw')", con);

int a = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

than

```
try {
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO DPMaster(DPID,DPName,ClientID,ClientName) VALUES('53','we','41','aw')", con);

    int a=com.ExecuteNonQuery();

} catch {
    MessageBox.Show("cannot");
}
```

Second, make use of `using` blocks as much as possible, since those blocks will dispose the no longer needed objects. So your code should look like this:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
    using (OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO DPMaster(DPID,DPName,ClientID,ClientName) VALUES('53','we','41','aw')", con) {

        con.Open();

        int a = com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
    }
```

With this code, you will more likely get to know what is going wrong while the exception will bubble up, plus, as soon as you'll quit the scope of the `using` blocks, resources used will be freed up as your objects will get disposed.

Comment: The code which i have pasted works fine without giving any error!!But the record is not inserted into database!!